# Ramer-Peucker-Douglas algorithm in polar coordinates

Tags: algorithm, geometry, simplification

I have points in polar coordinates (basically, I have a radar graph), and I want to eliminate points that are unnecessary the way Ramer-Peucker-Douglas does it in cartesian coordinates.

By unnecessary points I still mean a point B between points A and C and "close" to the line joining A to C, just like I the original Ramer-Peucker-Douglas algorithm (How close is "close" is an input parameter to the algorithm).

Any hints?

Comment: Transform your data from polar to Cartesian, use the Ramer-Peucker-Douglas algorithm. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system. That's probably the easiest to do. Otherwise you could write you're own  Ramer-Peucker-Douglas algorithm wich handles polar coordinates, but this probably a lot more work.

Comment: Indeed, rewriting the algorithm in polar coordinates would be an unnecessary pain in the neck (you would have to derive the equation of the distance from to point to a straight line in polar coordinates; simply plugging Theta, Rho for X, Y will not work).